# C#: Func<T, TResult> for generic methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

It is possible to create a [`Func` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) what references a generic method? like the LINQ [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

Comment: can u post a sample of how you intend to use it? I think its not exactly clear what you want to achieve from the description.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking if you can reference a generic method from within an anonymous method.

The answer is yes.

For example, suppose you want some `Func` that returns the elements of an `IEnumerable<int>` object in sorted order (precisely like `OrderBy<int, int>`). You could do this:

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, Func<int, int>, IOrderedEnumerable<int>> orderByFunc =
    System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<int, int>;
```

Then you could use this `Func` just like any other:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6, 9, 8 };

// here you're really calling OrderBy<int, int> --
// you've just stored its address in a variable of type Func<...>
foreach (int i in orderByFunc(ints, x => x))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

On the other hand, if you're asking whether it's possible to create a "generic anonymous method," like this:

```
Func<T> getDefault<T> = () => default(T);
```

Then it depends on your context. This can be done from within a context where `T` is already declared as a generic type parameter -- namely, within a generic class or generic method. (See Freddy Rios's answer.) Outside of such a context, unfortunately, it is illegal.

Comment: Thank you Dan! nice answer +1. you mean it is not possible to define a generic `Func` object? : O

Comment: @SDReyes: That depends on whether or not you have a `T` that is defined within your scope. That is, if you're working within a generic class, for example, then within a method in that class you might be able to declare a `Func<T>`. You could also do this within a generic method. But to declare a generic anonymous method in a context that isn't already generic (i.e., from within any plain vanilla non-generic method belonging to some non-generic class) is, I'm afraid, not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but it depends on the context - if you are already working with generics, just use the T in the context / if not, then you already know the specific type. In the later, if you need to reuse a bit of logic on a method, u probably already would benefit of moving that into a method, so just do like my second example below.

2 samples:

```
public T Something<T>() {
    Func<T> someFunc = () => { return default(T); };
    return someFunc();
}

public Func<T> GetDefaultCreator<T>() {
    return () => { return default(T); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`Func<Nullable<int>, string> myFunc = c => c.HasValue ? c.ToString() : "null";`

That successfully compiles, and you could assign any function to that that takes in a Nullable and returns a string.

Comment: Hi CubanX!, not really. you're referencing a lambda which takes a nullable object and return a string. I'm trying to reference a generic method (which receives a type TSource for example) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but you'll need to specify the type argument(s)

```
func<int> f = myClass.returnsT<int>;
```

where

```
class myClass
{
   T returnsT<T>()
   {...}
}
```

it Will not work without the type arguments

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this:

```
public static class Helper{

public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToPairs(this NameValueCollection Form)
        {
            return Form.AllKeys.Cast<string>()
                .Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, Form[key]));
        }
}
```

Where this method has become an extension method to the request.form in C# web development.

Comment: Hi Arne, thanks for your answer. nonetheless this is not a generic method. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it: Given the function `static TResult DoSomeStuff<T, TResult>(T obj)`, can you create a `Func<T, TResult>` such that it will reference the function above, with no type parameters given at the creation of the reference to it.
I think this could work (You're welcome to test it, I have no C# near me at the moment):

> ```
> class UselessClass<T, TResult>
> {
>    // If it's a static method, this is fine:
>     public Func<T, TResult> DaFunc = RelevantClass.DoSomeStuff<T, TResult>;
>     // If not, something like this is needed:
>     public UselessClass(SomeClassWhereTheFunctionIs from)
>     {
>        DaFunc = from.DoSomeStuff<T, TResult>;
>     }
> }
> ```

Also, in OrderBy, it's not actually a generic delegate. It's a declaration of a variable. When the function is given to it, the types are inferred from it.